# Can I use Typescript classes as AngularJS controllers using the new 'controller as' syntax

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs, coffeescript, typescript

I'm working on a web app using AngularJS and Typescript and I'm trying to find the best way to take advantage of Typescript when it comes to defining controllers. Intuitively a controller would just be a TypeScript class but AngularJS wants you to put everything into the $scope variable.

In the lasted Alpha release of AngularJS (1.1.5) they have added a new ['controller as' syntax](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTihyXaz4Bo). I've heard that this new syntax should help integrate with languages like Coffeescript and TypeScript but I don't quite understand how. If anyone has a sample of using this new syntax with TypeScript or CoffeeScript or can provide some insight into how it could be done I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it works fine. Just create your class e.g MainController. Then in your view use ng-controller='MainController as vm'. All properties of MainController class become members of $scope.vm

Comment: So all I have to do is create a class who's name matches whatever is in ng-controller and angular will call it's constructor? Also if I put parameters like $location and $log in the constructor will they be injected?

Comment: @rob yup. Just make sure the generated js is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me with CoffeeScript classes.

```
class MainCtrl
  newThing: ""
  constructor: (@model)->

  someThings: ->
    @model.awesomeThings

  addThing: ->
    @model.addThing(@newThing)


app.controller 'MainCtrl', ['ThingService', (model)-> 
    new MainCtrl(model)
]
```

You can see the full example on my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/50XKQQ).